# Abort form submission

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm currently working on a template editor for PDF generation. While the generation works just fine, the dynamic editing is giving me some trouble.

I'm submitting temporary forms which contain the templates:

```
//this is only the essence of the actual script
function updateTemplates(){
    $("#tmpForm").remove();
    $("#previewIFrame").remove();

    var frame = $("<iframe />");
    frame.attr("name","tplPreview");
    frame.attr("id","previewIFrame");

    var tmpForm = $("<form />");
    tmpForm.css("display","none");
    tmpForm.attr("id","tmpForm");
    tmpForm.attr("name","tplPreviewForm");
    tmpForm.attr("target","tplPreview");
    tmpForm.attr("method","post");
    tmpForm.attr("action","/preview.php");

    //append templates to form...

    $(".templatePreview").append(frame);
    $(".templatePreview").append(tmpForm);
    tmpForm.submit();
}
```

while that part works fine, i need to be able to abort the generation to submit a new set of templates. Since the iFrame should preview the pdf, i can't just use `$.ajax` which i would be able to `abort()`. Is there any way to abort the request that's sent by the form? Or maybe another way to preview the data that's sent back by the script (`application/pdf`)

Comment: I have no solution for you, but you definitely need to use an asynchronous request if you would like the chance to abort from your code.

Comment: which i stated that i can't use directly....if i need to use it, i'll need another way to show the result

Comment: It is possible to have a hidden `iFrame`. So one thing you might be able to do, is check the hidden iFrame - or have `tplPreview` hidden - and then parse through it to see if it is the proper template. Although, I'm not too sure about working with generated PDFs. I think your best bet is doing this after the form has been posted and a result returned. Just leave everything hidden to the user.

Comment: got a better idea, until someone says it's a bad idea....iframes accept data uirs...